# Maintain rownames when filter a data frame with %>%

Tags: r, dplyr

Look two codes below, myup1 maintain row names, myup2 does not.

```
myup1<-outdf2[outdf2$label == "Up-Regulated", ]
myup2<-outdf2 %>%filter(label == "Up-Regulated" )
```

Is there a way to report `rownames` with `%>%` approach?

Comment: dplyr doesn't *like* rownames, see `add_rownames()` to add rownames as a column before filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand my comment with an example, we can use `add_rownames` but it is deprecated, so use `tibble::rownames_to_column()` instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df1 <- mtcars[1:5, 1:3]
df1
#                    mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  3

df1[ df1$cyl == 6, ]
#                 mpg cyl disp
# Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160
# Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258

df1 %>%
  rownames_to_column("myCars") %>% 
  filter(cyl == 6)
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#           myCars   mpg   cyl  disp
#            <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      Mazda RX4  21.0     6   160
# 2  Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0     6   160
# 3 Hornet 4 Drive  21.4     6   258
```